# How to create printf effect in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, printf

How can I get my PowerShell script to print the info in tabular format as the script progresses.

In bash I would do this by

```bsh
printf "%s\t%-15.15s" "Locale" "Jar"
if($verbose);then
   printf "%-15.15s %-15.15s" "HelpSet" "Exception"
fi
printf "\t%s\n" "Status"
...
printf "%s\t%-15.15s" $locale $helpFileName
if($verbose); then
   printf "%-15.15s %-15.15s" "$helpSetName" ${exclusion[$helpFileName]}
fi
status="OK"
...
if ($fixed); then
   status="CORRECTED"
fi
printf "\t%s\n" $status
```

to get

```
Locale  Jar            HelpSet         Exception        Status
de      help_D150      help_D150                        CORRECTED

es      help_D150      help_D150                        OK

fr      help_D150      help_D150                        OK

it      Locale folder not found

nl      help_D150      help_D150                        CORRECTED
```

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this out in your PowerShell console:

```
"{0}`t{1,-15}{2,-15}{3,-15}" -f "Locale", "Jar", "HelpSet", "Exception"
```

You can use [string formatting](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) quite easily from PowerShell.

The [`-f` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) is a PowerShell short cut to the [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28VS.80%29.aspx) function, including all the [standard and custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28VS.80%29.aspx) formatting .NET types support.

Comment: With this approach two of the conditional columns are printed on a new line rather than on the same line

Comment: Use a single format string, combining all columns, and use $null or an empty string for the args you don't want to print.

Answer (score 4):

I have accepted Davids answer as that's what I asked for. However, I have chosen to create an object by

```
try{
    add-type @'
namespace FFPS {
    public class Data {
        public string Locale;
        public string JarFile;
        public string HelpSet;
        public string CorrectName;
        public string Status;
    }
}
'@
}
catch{}
```

and then use XML format file to format it as a table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>ffps.data</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>ffps.data</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Locale</Label>
                        <Width>6</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Jar File</Label>
                        <Width>16</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Help Set</Label>
                        <Width>16</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Correct Name</Label>
                        <Width>16</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Status</Label>
                        <Width>100</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.Locale</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.JarFile</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.HelpSet</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.CorrectName</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.Status</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

and in the code do

```
$currentFile = New-Object ffps.data
$currentFile.Locale = "DE"
$currentFile.JarFile = "JarFile.Name"
...
$currentFile
```

to print the entries